# Limit of quotient of $n$-th term of a converging series to its $n$-th tail.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find $$\lim _ { n \rightarrow \infty } \frac { 2 ^ { - n ^ { 2 } } } { \sum _ { k = n + 1 } ^ { \infty } 2 ^ { - k ^ { 2 } } }.$$

Clearly, this is the quotient of the $n$-th term of a converging series to its $n$-th tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} 2^{-k^2} < \sum_{j=(n+1)^2}^{\infty} 2^{-j} = 2^{-(n+1)^2}\cdot 2.$$

Thus our $n$th term is greater than

$$\frac { 2 ^ { - n ^ { 2 } } } { 2^{-(n+1)^2}\cdot 2} = 2^{2n} \to \infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Write the expression inside the limit as

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}}
{\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{{(n+1)}^2}} + \frac{1}{2^{{(n+2)}^2}} + \dots}
&=
\frac{1}
{\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{{(n+1)}^2 - n^2}} + \frac{1}{2^{{(n+2)}^2 - n^2}} + \dots}
\\&=
\frac{1}
{\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{4n+4}} + \dots}
\end{align}$$

So the expression is the reciprocal of

$$\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac1{2^{2kn+k^2}}\leqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac1{2^{2kn}} = \sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac1{{\left(4^n\right)}^k} = \frac1{4^n-1}$$

As $n$ approaches infinity...